# How to deal with NULL value in a column which should be a primary key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, schema, unique

We have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE UserSettings (
     id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
     user_id int(11),
     setting_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     setting_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

UserID is a foreign key into a Users table. We would like to be able to put default settings into this table by having a row with user_id = NULL.

The issue is that we want to enforce that there is only one row with NULL in the UserID column. You can't have a unique constraint across multiple columns if one of the columns can be NULL.

We thought about making the used_id column NOT NULL, and using some default value like -1 for the default, but then you can't have foreign keys because there is no User with an id of -1.

The next idea was to have a SettingsType table which contained all setting_names with unique ids, and then two tables, one for default settings and another for user settings.

```
CREATE TABLE SettingTypes (
   id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   setting_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE UserSettings (
   id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   setting_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   setting_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE DefaultSettings (
   id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   setting_type_id int(11) NOT NULL,
   setting_value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

This works well, except that if you want to iterate through all settings, both defaults and per user, you have two tables to iterate through.

The last implementation we came up with was to normalize one more time, by having the following tables `SettingTypes`, `Settings`, `UserSettings`, `DefaultSettings`. Where there are foriegn keys from `UserSettings` and `DefaultSettings` into the `Settings` table.

This seems like the best solution, but there does not seem to be a good way to make sure that a `Setting` in the `DefaultSettings` is not also used by a `UserSetting`

What other schemas have you used to solve these problems?
Are there any books talk about database patterns?

Comment: "...because there is no User with an id of -1." Why not?

Comment: There is no User in the user table with an id of -1 because it's not a real user. We were just thinking about using -1 in the user_id column of the UserSettings table so we could add a unique constraint for (user_id, setting_name)

Comment: The point of "Why not?" is simply to say that a "Not real user" record could simply be added to satisfy the database requirement. So, why wouldn't such a record be added? I can think of various reasons, but they might not apply for you; so I'm asking why you don't create such a record and eliminate the problem.

Comment: The reason is that you then have to filter that user out of other queries all over the system. One solution is to separate put all settings in a single table and then have two tables, one for defaults, and one that is per user, with links back to the settings table.

Comment: A filter could (should?) simply be a VIEW that excluded that UserID.

Comment: I think the use of two tables makes more sense. I don't like polluting the user table with a pseudo user.

Comment: No disagreement, especially if you can justify your choices. My first question was simply to clarify your situation. I don't have anything better than your concept that fits.